# How do I enable Terminal Services in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: terminal-server, windows-server-2003

I've just installed Windows Server 2003 and want to enable Terminal Services for Remote Administration.  I've checked the Terminal Services Manager, Terminal Services Licencing and Terminal Services Configuration tools under "Administration" in the Start Menu, but can't find the option to turn it on.  How do I enable Terminal Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...  Open the Start Menu, right click on "My Computer" and select "Properties".  Click on the "Remote" tab, and tick "ENable Remote Desktop on this computer".

It's in exactly the same place as it is in XP, but somehow I spent hours looking fior it in Windows Server 2003.

Jim.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Windows Components in Add / Remove Programs and select it as an addable component.  It's not installed by default.